# Why does my store procedure throw error when enclosed within transaction block else not?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Why my code throws an error:

**Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0**

When I remove Transaction blocks then it works fine but not with those blocks. Why ?

I have testing it for the last 2 days but still it throws too many erors which it should not but still it does. Please help me on it.

Code:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[ContractRegistration] 
@ContractorType_ID tinyint, 
@RegistrationDate  date, 
@ExpiryDate        date, 
@Email             varchar(200), 
@FName             varchar(50), 
@Mobile            varchar(50), 
@Name              varchar(50), 
@CNIC              varchar(20), 
@ContactNo         varchar(20), 
@Password          varchar(200), 
@IsActive          bit                                  = 0, 
@User_ID           smallint, 
@Organization_ID   int, 
@District_ID       smallint, 
@ContractorID      int, 
@EnlistmentNo      varchar(50), 
@Address           varchar(300), 
@OfficeID          int, 
@PECCategoryID     int, 
@PECCategoryNo     varchar(50), 
@CNWEnlistmentNo   varchar(50), 
@NTN               varchar(50), 
@SPCode            [dbo].[ContractorSpecializationCode] READONLY, 
@Doc               [dbo].[ContractorDocuments] READONLY, 
@Farm              varchar(200), 
@TaxExempted       bit, 
@BankCode          varchar(20), 
@BankName          varchar(20), 
@BankDraft         varchar(30), 
@Amount            money, 
@RenwalID          int                                  = 0, 
@ExpectedDate      date=null, 
@PecReciptNo       varchar(50),
@IsRenewal BIT,
@RoleID int= 2
AS
BEGIN
  Begin Try
    Begin Transaction tran1
/*
THIS STORED PROCEDURE IS CALLED FOR CONTRACTOR SAVING, UPDATION AND RENWAL...
-- IN CASE OF RENEWAL OLD REGISTRATION, OLD SPECIALZATION CODE AND OLD DOCUMENTS HISTORY IS MAINTAINED IN HISTORY TABLES.
-- IN CASE OF SAVING NEW ENTRY IS DONE, IN CONTRACTOR, SPECIALZATION CODES AND DOCUMENTS.
-- IN CASE OF UPDATION REGISTION SPECIALZTION AND DOUCMENTS ARE UPDATED..
*/
    /* Constractor Status
    1: New
    2 : Approved
    3: Deffered
    4: Rejected
    5 : Approved with c&W Exemption
    */

    ----------------------------- PEC Cat and Category validation
        if(@PECCategoryID = 1 AND (@ContractorType_ID NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 10))
        Begin
                RAISERROR('Category must be between PK-1 and PK-10 for C-A ',16,1);
                RETURN;
        End
        if(@PECCategoryID = 2 AND (@ContractorType_ID NOT BETWEEN 2 AND 10))
        Begin
                RAISERROR('Category must be between PK-2 and PK-10 for C-B ',16,1);
                RETURN;
        End
        if(@PECCategoryID = 3 AND (@ContractorType_ID NOT BETWEEN 3 AND 10))
        Begin
                RAISERROR('Category must be between PK-3 and PK-10 for C-1 ',16,1);
                RETURN;
        End
        if(@PECCategoryID = 4 AND (@ContractorType_ID NOT BETWEEN 4 AND 10))
        Begin
                RAISERROR('Category must be between PK-4 and PK-10 for C-2 ',16,1);
                RETURN;
        End
        if(@PECCategoryID = 5 AND (@ContractorType_ID NOT BETWEEN 5 AND 10))
        Begin
                RAISERROR('Category must be between PK-5 and PK-10 for C-3',16,1);
                RETURN;
        End
        if(@PECCategoryID = 6 AND (@ContractorType_ID NOT BETWEEN 6 AND 10))
        Begin
                RAISERROR('Category must be between PK-6 and PK-10 for C-4 ',16,1);
                RETURN;
        End
        if(@PECCategoryID = 7 AND (@ContractorType_ID NOT BETWEEN 7 AND 10))
        Begin
                RAISERROR('Category must be between PK-7 and PK-10 for C-5 ',16,1);
                RETURN;
        End
        if(@PECCategoryID = 8 AND (@ContractorType_ID NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 10))
        Begin
                RAISERROR('Category must be between PK-8 and PK-10 for C-6 ',16,1);
                RETURN;
        End




    ----------------------------- PEC Cat and Category validation

DECLARE @CurrentStatus int,@HistoryID int;
    -------- If New Entry...
IF @IsRenewal=0
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT ContractorID FROM dbo.Contractors WHERE ContractorID = @ContractorID)
        BEGIN

        ----- SMS section (if contractor mobile no has been modified then sms must be sent to the contractor and MIS manager)

                Declare @OldMobileNo varchar(20)
                Set @OldMobileNo= ISNULL((Select c.ContactNo from Contractors c where c.ContractorID= @ContractorID),0)

                IF(@OldMobileNo not like @Mobile)
                Begin

                       Declare @ContractorName varchar(200)
                       Set @ContractorName= (Select c.Name from dbo.Contractors c where c.ContractorID= @ContractorID)

                       Declare @OrganizationID int
                       Set @OrganizationID= (Select c.Organization_ID from dbo.Contractors c where c.ContractorID= @ContractorID)

                       DECLARE @smsbody NVARCHAR(MAX);
                       Declare @smsbody_MIS NVARCHAR(MAX);                 

                       SET @smsbody = 'Your mobile no. has been changed to '+ @Mobile +'. '+'If you have any query regarding this change then contact system admin.'
                       SET @smsbody_MIS= @ContractorName + ' '+ 'mobile no. has been changed to '+ @Mobile 

                       Declare @EntryDate date
                       Set @EntryDate= (Select GETDATE())

                       EXEC MC_SMS.App.SaveQueueSMSSingle @smsbody,@OldMobileNo,1,1,1,0, @EntryDate, @OrganizationID
                       EXEC MC_SMS.App.SaveQueueSMSSingle @smsbody_MIS,'03369883499',1,1,1,0, @EntryDate, @OrganizationID -- send a copy to MIS manager

                 End

       ----- SMS section



            DELETE FROM [dbo].[SpecializationCodeContractor]
            WHERE Contractor_ID = @ContractorID;
            DELETE FROM [dbo].[DocumentContractor]
            WHERE Contractor_ID = @ContractorID;
            --delete from dbo.ContractorRenewal where  ID=@RenwalID

            UPDATE [dbo].[Contractors]
              SET [ContractorType_ID] = @ContractorType_ID, [RegistrationDate] = @RegistrationDate, [RegExpiryDate] = @ExpiryDate, [Name] = @Name, [FatherName] = @FName, 
              [CNIC] = @CNIC, [ContactNo] = @Mobile, [PhoneNo] = @ContactNo, [EnlistmentNo] = @EnlistmentNo, 
            [Password] = @Password, [Organization_ID] = @Organization_ID, [DistrictID] = @District_ID, [User_ID] = @User_ID, [Office_ID] = @OfficeID, 
            [Address] = @Address, [Email] = @Email, [PecCategoryID] = @PECCategoryID, [PECCategoryNo] = @PECCategoryNo, 
            [CNWEnlistmentNo] = @CNWEnlistmentNo, [NTN] = @NTN, [HasTaxExempted] = @TaxExempted, [Farm] = @Farm,UpdatedBy=@User_ID, UpdatedDate=GETDATE()
            WHERE ContractorID = @ContractorID;

                ----------------------------------------- Maintain History
            INSERT INTO ContractorsHistory (ContractorID, ContractorType_ID, RegistrationDate, RegExpiryDate, Name, FatherName, CNIC, ContactNo, PhoneNo, EnlistmentNo, Password, 
            Organization_ID, DistrictID, User_ID, IsActive, EntryDateTime, LastLoginDate, Office_ID, Address, Email, PECCategoryID, PECCategoryNo, CNWEnlistmentNo, NTN, Status, HasTaxExempted, Farm, ApprovedBy, ApprovedDate, PECReceiptNo, ExpectedDate,UpdatedBy,UpdateDate)
            SELECT ContractorID, ContractorType_ID, RegistrationDate, RegExpiryDate, Name, FatherName, CNIC, ContactNo, PhoneNo, EnlistmentNoNew, Password, 
            Organization_ID, DistrictID, User_ID, IsActive, EntryDateTime, LastLoginDate, Office_ID, Address, Email,PECCategoryID, PECCategoryNo, CNWEnlistmentNo, NTN, Status, HasTaxExempted, Farm, ApprovedBy, ApprovedDate, PECReceiptNo, ExpectedDate,UpdatedBy,UpdatedDate 
            FROM Contractors WHERE ContractorID=@ContractorID;

            SELECT @CurrentStatus = Status
            FROM Contractors
            WHERE ContractorID = @ContractorID;

            IF @CurrentStatus = 5 ---5 : Approved with c&W Exemption
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dbo.SpecializationCodeContractor
                       SELECT SP_ID, @ContractorID
                       FROM @SPCode s
                       JOIN SpecializationCodes SP ON SP.SpecializationID = S.SP_ID
                       WHERE SP.SpecCategory_ID = 4; -----Electrical Engineering
            END;
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dbo.SpecializationCodeContractor
                       SELECT SP_ID, @ContractorID
                       FROM @SPCode;
            END;
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[DocumentContractor]
                   SELECT Doc_ID, @ContractorID
                   FROM @Doc;

            -- insert into [dbo].[ContractorRenewal]
            -- select @ContractorID,@BankCode,@BankName,@BankDraft,@ExpiryDate,@Amount,GETDATE()


            UPDATE [dbo].[ContractorRenewal]
              SET [BankCode] = @BankCode, [BankName] = @BankName, [BankDraftNo] = @BankDraft, [ValidUpto] = @ExpiryDate, [Amount] = @Amount, [RenwalDate] = @RegistrationDate
            WHERE ID = @RenwalID;

        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN   --- save new contractor

            -------------------auto enlistment no generation------------------
            declare @MaxContractorID int
            Set @MaxContractorID= (SELECT ISNULL(max(c.contractorID),0) FROM Contractors c where Office_ID= @OfficeID)

            declare @CurrentYear varchar(4)
            Set @CurrentYear = (Select YEAR(getdate()))

            declare @EnlistmentNoNew varchar(20)    --- format= OfficeIDCurrentYearMaxContractorID
            set @EnlistmentNoNew= (Select CAST(@OfficeID as varchar) + @CurrentYear + CAST(@MaxContractorID as varchar))

            -------------------auto enlistment no generation------------------

            INSERT INTO [dbo].[Contractors]([ContractorType_ID], [RegistrationDate], [RegExpiryDate], [Name], [FatherName], [CNIC], [ContactNo], [PhoneNo], [EnlistmentNo], 
            [Password], [Organization_ID], [DistrictID], [User_ID], [IsActive], [EntryDateTime], [LastLoginDate], [Office_ID], [address], [Email], [PECCategoryID], 
            [PECCategoryNo], [CNWEnlistmentNo], [ntn], [HasTaxExempted], [Status], [Farm], PECReceiptNo, ExpectedDate, EnlistmentNoNew)
            VALUES(@ContractorType_ID, @RegistrationDate, @ExpiryDate, @Name, @FName, @CNIC, @Mobile, @ContactNo, @EnlistmentNo, @Password, @Organization_ID, @District_ID, 
            @User_ID, 0, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), @OfficeID, @Address, @Email, @PECCategoryID, @PECCategoryNo, @CNWEnlistmentNo, @NTN, @TaxExempted, 1, @Farm, 
            @PecReciptNo, @ExpectedDate, @EnlistmentNoNew);

            DECLARE @Con_ID int;
            SELECT @Con_ID = IDENT_CURRENT('[dbo].[Contractors]');
            ----------------------------------------- Maintain History
            INSERT INTO ContractorsHistory (ContractorID, ContractorType_ID, RegistrationDate, RegExpiryDate, Name, FatherName, CNIC, ContactNo, PhoneNo, EnlistmentNo, Password, 
            Organization_ID, DistrictID, User_ID, IsActive, EntryDateTime, LastLoginDate, Office_ID, Address, Email, PECCategoryID, PECCategoryNo, CNWEnlistmentNo, NTN, Status, HasTaxExempted, Farm, ApprovedBy, ApprovedDate, PECReceiptNo, ExpectedDate)
                                     SELECT ContractorID, ContractorType_ID, RegistrationDate, RegExpiryDate, Name, FatherName, CNIC, ContactNo, PhoneNo, EnlistmentNoNew, Password, 
                                     Organization_ID, DistrictID, User_ID, IsActive, EntryDateTime, LastLoginDate, Office_ID, Address, Email, PECCategoryID, PECCategoryNo, CNWEnlistmentNo, NTN, Status, HasTaxExempted, Farm, ApprovedBy, ApprovedDate, PECReceiptNo, ExpectedDate 
                                     FROM Contractors WHERE ContractorID=@Con_ID;

            Set @HistoryID= IDENT_CURRENT('ContractorsHistory')

            INSERT INTO dbo.SpecializationCodeContractor
                   SELECT SP_ID, @Con_ID
                   FROM @SPCode;

            INSERT INTO [dbo].[DocumentContractor]
                   SELECT Doc_ID, @Con_ID
                   FROM @Doc;

            IF @Amount > 0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[ContractorRenewal](Contractor_ID,BankCode,BankName,BankDraftNo,ValidUpto,Amount,RenwalDate,ContractorHistory_ID)
                       SELECT @Con_ID, @BankCode, @BankName, @BankDraft, @ExpiryDate, @Amount, @RegistrationDate,@HistoryID;
            END;

        END;
    END
    ELSE
    ----- Renewal Section...
    BEGIN
    --------------- Maintain Previous Year Documents and Specializtion COde in History Tables..
    SELECT TOP  1 @HistoryID=HistoryID FROM ContractorsHistory WHERE ContractorID=@ContractorID ORDER BY HistoryID DESC;
        ----------------- Specialization Code history...
        INSERT INTO SpecializationCodeContractorHistory (SP_ID,Contractor_ID,ContractorHistory_ID)
        SELECT SP_ID,Contractor_ID,@HistoryID from SpecializationCodeContractor WHERE Contractor_ID=@ContractorID;
        ---------------------- Documents History.....

        INSERT INTO DocumentContractorHistory (Doc_ID,Contractor_ID,ContractorHistory_ID)
        SELECT Doc_ID,Contractor_ID,@HistoryID FROM DocumentContractor WHERE Contractor_ID=@ContractorID;
        ----------------------

        -------------------auto enlistment no generation------------------
            declare @MaxContractorID1 int
            Set @MaxContractorID1= (SELECT ISNULL(max(c.contractorID),0) FROM Contractors c where Office_ID= @OfficeID)

            declare @CurrentYear1 varchar(4)
            Set @CurrentYear1 = (Select YEAR(getdate()))

            declare @EnlistmentNoNew1 varchar(20)    --- format= OfficeIDCurrentYearMaxContractorID
            set @EnlistmentNoNew1= (Select CAST(@OfficeID as varchar) + @CurrentYear1 + CAST(@MaxContractorID1 as varchar))
        -------------------auto enlistment no generation------------------

            UPDATE [dbo].[Contractors]
              SET [ContractorType_ID] = @ContractorType_ID, [RegistrationDate] = @RegistrationDate, [RegExpiryDate] = @ExpiryDate, [Name] = @Name, [FatherName] = @FName, 
              [CNIC] = @CNIC, [ContactNo] = @Mobile, [PhoneNo] = @ContactNo, [EnlistmentNo] = @EnlistmentNo, 
            [Password] = @Password, [Organization_ID] = @Organization_ID, [DistrictID] = @District_ID, [User_ID] = @User_ID, [Office_ID] = @OfficeID, 
            [Address] = @Address, [Email] = @Email, [PecCategoryID] = @PECCategoryID, [PECCategoryNo] = @PECCategoryNo, 
            [CNWEnlistmentNo] = @CNWEnlistmentNo, [NTN] = @NTN, [HasTaxExempted] = @TaxExempted, [Farm] = @Farm,UpdatedBy=@User_ID,UpdatedDate=GETDATE(), EnlistmentNoNew=@EnlistmentNoNew1
            WHERE ContractorID = @ContractorID;

        ----------- Save History...
        INSERT INTO ContractorsHistory (ContractorID, ContractorType_ID, RegistrationDate, RegExpiryDate, Name, FatherName, CNIC, ContactNo, 
                    PhoneNo, EnlistmentNo, Password, Organization_ID, DistrictID, User_ID, IsActive, EntryDateTime, LastLoginDate, Office_ID, 
                    Address, Email, PECCategoryID, PECCategoryNo, CNWEnlistmentNo, NTN, Status, HasTaxExempted, Farm, ApprovedBy, ApprovedDate, PECReceiptNo, ExpectedDate,UpdateDate,UpdatedBy)
        SELECT ContractorID, ContractorType_ID, RegistrationDate, RegExpiryDate, Name, FatherName, CNIC, ContactNo, PhoneNo, EnlistmentNoNew, 
                    Password, Organization_ID, DistrictID, User_ID, IsActive, EntryDateTime, LastLoginDate, Office_ID, Address, Email, PECCategoryID, 
                    PECCategoryNo, CNWEnlistmentNo, NTN, Status, HasTaxExempted, Farm, ApprovedBy, ApprovedDate, PECReceiptNo, ExpectedDate,UpdatedDate,UpdatedBy FROM Contractors
        WHERE ContractorID=@ContractorID;


        DELETE FROM [dbo].[SpecializationCodeContractor]
        WHERE Contractor_ID = @ContractorID;
        ----------------------------------------
        DELETE FROM [dbo].[DocumentContractor]
        WHERE Contractor_ID = @ContractorID;
            --delete from dbo.ContractorRenewal where  ID=@RenwalID

            SELECT @CurrentStatus = Status
            FROM Contractors
            WHERE ContractorID = @ContractorID;

            IF @CurrentStatus = 5 ---5 : Approved with c&W Exemption
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dbo.SpecializationCodeContractor
                       SELECT SP_ID, @ContractorID
                       FROM @SPCode s
                       JOIN SpecializationCodes SP ON SP.SpecializationID = S.SP_ID
                       WHERE SP.SpecCategory_ID = 4; -----Electrical Engineering
            END;
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dbo.SpecializationCodeContractor
                       SELECT SP_ID, @ContractorID
                       FROM @SPCode;
            END;
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[DocumentContractor]
                   SELECT Doc_ID, @ContractorID
                   FROM @Doc;

            -- insert into [dbo].[ContractorRenewal]
            -- select @ContractorID,@BankCode,@BankName,@BankDraft,@ExpiryDate,@Amount,GETDATE()

            IF EXISTS(SELECT Contractor_ID FROM ContractorRenewal WHERE ValidUpto=@ExpiryDate AND Contractor_ID=@ContractorID)
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('Payment Entry already exists for selected Renewal Year!',16,1);
                RETURN;
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[ContractorRenewal] (Contractor_ID,BankCode,BankName,BankDraftNo,ValidUpto,Amount,RenwalDate)
                VALUES  ( @ContractorID, @BankCode, @BankName, @BankDraft, @ExpiryDate, @Amount, @RegistrationDate);
            END
        END

    Commit Transaction 

 End Try
 Begin Catch
    rollback transaction
 End Catch
END;
```

Update: On the suggestion:

C# end

```
public static bool SaveContractor(clsAdmin A, bool IsRenewal = false)
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("[dbo].ContractRegistration", OpenConnection());
    bool result = false;
    SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        com.Transaction = tran;
        // // Passing DataTable to SP...
        SqlParameter sp = com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPCode", A.dt);
        sp.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        SqlParameter sp1 = com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Doc", A.dtDoc);
        sp1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractorID", A.ContractorID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractorType_ID", A.CategoryID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationDate", A.RegistractionDate);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpiryDate", A.ExpiryDate);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", A.Email);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", A.FName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", A.Mobile);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", A.Name);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNIC", A.CNIC);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", A.Contact);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", A.Password);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", 1);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_ID", A.UserID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Organization_ID", A.OrganizationID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@District_ID", A.DistrictID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnlistmentNo", A.EnlistmentNo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", A.Address);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficeID", A.OfficeID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PECCategoryID", A.PECCategoryID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PECCategoryNo", A.PECCategoryNo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNWEnlistmentNo", A.CNWEnlistmentNo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NTN", A.NTN);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Farm", A.Farm);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaxExempted", A.TaxExe);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BankCode", A.BankCode);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BankName", A.BankName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BankDraft", A.BankDraftNo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", A.Amount);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RenwalID", A.ReID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PecReciptNo", A.PecReciptNo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpectedDate", A.ExpectedDate);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsRenewal", IsRenewal);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleID", A.RoleID);

        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        result = com.ExecuteNonQuery().ToBool();
        tran.Commit();
        CloseConnection();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tran.Rollback();
        CloseConnection();
        throw ex;

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: maybe you are missing an `END` somewhere? bit too much code and not the best alignment, hard to say for sure

Comment: you are handling a transaction inside your procedure. When the caller of this procedure also starts a transaction before calling it, it will get this error after finishing because you ended this transaction. It is always tricky to do transaction handling inside procedures because you cannot know if the calles also does transaction handling

Comment: @GuidoG any way to resolve this ?

Comment: don't use transaction inside procedures

Comment: @GuidoG what if some line throws error and it doesn't execute but others does then it would create a lot of inconsistencies across the tables ?

Comment: so where to use ?

Comment: I always let the caller handle transaction, if the procedure returns an error (which it does in your case) then the caller shows the error and does rollback. When no errors the caller does commit. Simple and effective

Comment: The rollback will rollback ALL changes, so no change in inconstistincies across tables

Comment: @GuidoG: check my updated part in question if it;s correct 

PS i have remove transaction block from SP

Comment: you still start a transaction in your procedure,and still commit or rollback

Comment: @GuidoG: in a stored Procedure ? No, from there i Have removed but havent updated the code above or if there's anything else ?

Comment: @GuidoG: i am a naive so might not be getting you fully.

Comment: Just remove anything from transaction from the stored procedure and you will be fine

Comment: Can you please describe what happens when you execute the stored procedure from SSMS, rather than from C# code? Is the behavior different? That should indicate where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already using a transaction in app code, that's why, when you commit or rollback a transaction in the procedure, app code find nothing to commit. and you are getting this exception.

Actually, you don't need any additional transaction in the procedure. One of them enough.